Equations for the Winkler method
I learned in my IB chemistry class that the chemical equations for the Winkler method are as follows.
Step 1　2Mn2+(aq) + 4OH-(aq) + O2(aq) → 2MnO2(s) + 2H2O(l)
Step 2　MnO2(s) + 2I-(aq) + 4H+(aq) → Mn2+(aq) + I2(aq) + 2H2O(l)
Step 3　2S2O32-(aq) + I2(aq) → S4O62-(aq) + 2I-(aq)
However, I was doing some research on the Winkler method for my chemistry IA and found the following equations:
Step 1　2Mn2+(aq) + O2(aq) + 4OH– → 2MnO(OH)2(s)
Step 2　MnO(OH)2(s) + 2I–(aq) + 4H+ → Mn2+(aq) + I2(aq) + 3H2O
Step 3　I–(aq) + I2(aq) → I3–(aq)
Step 4　2S2O32-(aq) + I3–(aq) → S4O62-(aq) + 3I–(aq)
Why are the equations different?

The exact oxidation state and form of oxidized $\ce{Mn(OH)2}$ is not well defined and existence of $\ce{I3-}$ is sometimes ignored for simplification

The difference between $\ce{MnO2}$ and $\ce{MnO(OH)2}$ is just one water molecule. Nobody knows if and how $\ce{MnO2}$ is more or less hydrated in this system.

The step 1 should be also divided to coagulation of manganese(II) hydroxide in alkalic pH, followed by its oxidation by the dissolved oxygen, as the latter is much slower.

Chem+Math MathJax formatting:
Basics / Expressions/formulas/equations / Upright vs Italics / Math SE Mathjax tutorial
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Consider using the syntax $\ce{I-(aq) + I2(aq) -> I3-(aq)}$ to get $\ce{I-(aq) + I2(aq) -> I3-(aq)}$. Or $\ce{MnO2(s) + 2I-(aq) + 4H+(aq) -> Mn2+(aq) + I2(aq) + 2 H2O(l)}$ for $\ce{MnO2(s) + 2I-(aq) + 4H+(aq) -> Mn2+(aq) + I2(aq) + 2 H2O(l)}$   // Or double dollars as the usual MathJax display mode instead on the inline mode:
$$\ce{I-(aq) + I2(aq) -> I3-(aq)}$$
